# Why does 12.0 == 11.999999999999999999999 is considered as true?

Tags: c++

Can somebody give me an in-depth explanation of what's going on?
The system considers approximation right?(correct me if I'm wrong)
I would like to know how the computer behaves in these kinds of situation. Thank you.

Comment: https://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 1):

Normal numbers in computers are stored with only so many bits of precision. A float in C++ is typically 4 bytes. 32 bits can't store that many 9s of precision, so the compiler does rounding to the precision it can handle.

Basically, you get approximately 10 digits of precision in total, and you have a lot more 9s than that.

Comment: Please don't answer obvious dupes.  We have a great canonical for Q's like this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken